# Application installer requires KB to be installed even though it's already installed

Tags: windows-7, installation, windows-update

Happy Friday!

I'm having an issue with an application in where it keeps asking for KB2999226 to be installed even though the KB is already installed. I have spoken to our local Application Support team and they suffer the same issue on this PC with elevated privileges.

### PC SPECS

OS: Windows 7 SP1 (32-Bit)

RAM: 4GB

CPU: Pentium Dual Core E588 @ 3.20GHz

### APPLICATION SPECS

HDD: 100MB

RAM: 512MB

OS: Windows 7 SP1 (x86 & x64)

Client Version: 1.171

The PC in question meets all the minimum requirements that are listed in the client install manual.

[image: Install Wizard asking for KB, and KB clearly being listed as installed]

When the "Install" button is clicked on the Wizard it begins to install the KB but never actually confirms it has "Succeeded" (All other pre-reqs returned with a status of "Success") it just appears to close the Wizard and continue with the install.

The application has installed on the PC i.e. I am able to run the program. However, whenever I click on certain functions the application bombs out, all with the same error message.

[image: Error Message and then App Crash]

I have run this application whilst using ProcMon but could not find anything that look suspicious or causing the error to crash, which leads me to believe that the KB either isn't installed properly or the Application (for whatever reason) is unable to see that the KB is installed.

I appreciate that there is not much information provided, but there really isn't much else that is displayed during the process of installing to failure, or anything that I have found so far, so apologies on that front.

The next items to check on my list are comparing installed Programs, Hotfixes, and KBs of a PC that it is working on, however, I'd appreciate the input of anyone who has had a similar issue and any advise you may have to give.

Thanks,
Josh

### Update 1

I have checked the Windows Updates on another machine and the KB that is being requested by the installer is not even installed the on the working machine.

Comment: The `KB2999226` update package should be superseded by [`KB3118401`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2999226/update-for-universal-c-runtime-in-windows). Have you tried manually uninstalling the **Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable Package**, and then installing [latest supported version](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads)?

Comment: "I have checked the Windows Updates on another machine and the KB that is being requested by the installer is not even installed the on the working machine." This incates you have the patch that superseded the patch being installed, but if it still crashes on the working machine , that's an **application bug**

Answer (score 0):

The fix to this was a .OCX file had become deregistered. Running REGSVR32 and pointing it to the relevant .OCX file fixed this issue.

Clearly, the Windows Updates were leading me down a false path relating to the App Crash.

I will update the KB to the newest version as suggested in the comments by  and31415.

Thanks for all your suggestions.

Thanks,

Josh